# Small install script in sh

Tags: linux, installation, sh

I programmed a small installation program in sh.

code:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $ 1

if [ "$1" ! = "install"];

then

echo "Why not install?

else

echo "Installing ..."

fi
```

And throws an error:

install

[: 10: missing ]

Installing ...

**EDIT**: Rolled back incoperation of answers into question.

Comment: There must be no space between ! and =

Comment: @Zygimantas Magelinskas , you edited the original question, edited it so as to fix the problems which were actually complained about -- hence the answers may not make sense with the question as it stand now -- this corrupt the entire reason for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [$1 != "install"];
```

should be

```
if [ "$1" != "install" ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems here

The first line should start with

```
   #!/bin/bash (or /bin/sh)
```

In shell script `if` takes a program, and `[` is actually a program (it is an alias for the `test` program), and not a part of the syntax, so you need to make sure you space it out so that if and the '[' and anything out is separated out -- i.e.

```
  if  [  "$1"  !=  "something"  ]
```

**Note** the spaces between each and every element -- it will not work without spaces.

You also need to terminate your quoted strings, so instead of

```
 echo "Why not install?
```

Make sure you have the quote at the end of line

```
 echo "Why not install?"
```

Comment: What part of it?  The error you complain about, is due to the arguments on the IF statement not being spaced correctly.  However the other issues will cause you problems as well.